# Tracking how many times value went below or above threshold based on list

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have list with values, and I'm looking for way to track if those values went below certain value, and then if they went back up above it (possibly number of times)

So let's say my lisy looks like:

```
list1 = [20, 18, 16, 15, 13, 12, 16, 17, 14, 11, 16]
```

And I need something that will tell me, that values went back up above 15 two or x number of times after it initially went below 15.
Anyone knows how to tackle this problem?

Comment: so in this list, it went below twice (13,12) and then rose to 16. So 2?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: After it went below once (13 and further) it went back above twice: (16, 17) and (16) - last one in list

Comment: @RoryDaulton Ok... but I really have no idea how to begin to solve this problem and any code was just useless gibberish. I can post script that i'm working on, but in other parts of it there is nothing helpful. Sorry for thinking, that someone might had same problem and could tell me: "use :that function from module x". And any description that i tried in google points me into completely different direction (CV2 and image processing for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pos_count = 0
neg_count = 0 

for x in range(len(list1)-1):
    if list1[x] <= 15 and list1[x + 1] > 15:
        neg_count += 1
    elif list1[x] >= 15 and list1[x + 1] < 15:
        pos_count += 1

print(pos_count)
print(neg_count)
```

Comment: I am not sure in python whether `if x <= 15 and list1[num + 1] > 15:` throws index out of range exception for last index in list

Comment: It works, there are no exceptions while running this code, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check the negative/positive difference from 15.
Something like this:

```
l = [20, 18, 16, 15, 13, 12, 16, 17, 14, 11, 16] #Your list

import numpy as np
arr = np.asarray(l) #Convert to numpy-array

#Now apply the function to check the difference from 15
result = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x - 15, axis=0, arr=arr)
```

This results in:
array([ 5,  3,  1,  0, -2, -3,  1,  2, -1, -4,  1])

If you want to check all positive values, you can do it like this:

```
pos = result[result >= 0] #All positive values
neg = result[result <  0] #All negative values
```

If you want to count how often this happens, you can count the length:

```
len(pos) #Number of positives
len(neg) #Number of negatives
```

Comment: Thx for answer though other answer is giving better results for me. But it might be still useful later on. Thx again